# Spatial join with a calculated WHERE comparison for >1 result

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I am attempting to identify households which are downstream and within 5km of another set of point features (water sources). We are defining downstream as being at a lower altitude than the water source, so `water_source_altitude - household_altitude > 0`.

In several instances I have water sources with overlapping 5km buffers, and there are households that fall within this overlap. If household A falls within a 5km buffer of water source 1 and water source 2, is closest to and upstream of water source 1, and is downstream of water source 2, then a spatial join will not identify the correct water source for this household. Is there a way to include criteria which would calculate (`water source 1 altitude - household altitude`) and (`water source 2 altitude - household altitude`), and choose the water source where result > 0? I've looked at a few other questions about spatial joins and criteria, but they aren't quite what I'm looking for.

By the way, I am running a Basic license of ArcMap 10.2.2 and my knowledge of python is very limited. I feel like the answer could involve PostGres or PostGIS, but I am not quite sure where to start with those.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you include an image in the question maybe showing a couple examples of this relationship in ArcMap and what the end result should be?

Comment: You could set the join to 'ONE TO MANY'; run the join; run your calculation for the water altitude; query out any negative altitudes.

Answer (score 1):

one workaround is to work with some spatial analysis, focusing on height and not on distance:

- use point statistics tool with a circular neighbourhood and the maximum value
- use extract multivalue to point in order to extract the value of the above raster for each household.
- with a field selection, you can now find the household downstream of at least one source in a 5 km radius.

remark: you could use the same logic with your buffers and spatial join (join one to one) to get the maximum latitude of the watersources within 5km.